# Hibernate-Spring how do I turn my save into a update or save?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate-Spring how do I turn my save into a update or save??

I am using the following code in my system but if a dealer with the same rUser is in the table I would like to update the row.  how can I do this?

```
public void saveDealer(Dealer dealer, String rUser) {

    dealer.setUsername(rUser);
    dealer.setAddedDate(new Date());
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(dealer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `saveOrUpdate`
the hibernate will save your data if the data with specific ID is not exists and It will update your data if the data with specific ID is exists

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/engine/Cascade.html

Another approach is to check before `saveOrUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a check for existing record before. There is no automatic way for Hibernate to figure out if a dealer record exists for a particular user and take a decision about save or update. I wish software could think :-)

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's worth noting that it's possible to do this for most databases with SQL something like "INSERT, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".

Answer (score 0):

Almost all my entities contains Identity field like Long id. so, my save() method looks like this:

```
void save(EntityWithId entity) {
    if (entity == null)
        return;
    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        session.persist(entity);
    } else {
        session.merge(entity);
    }
}
```